# In Excel, how to transform a colum with several kind of data types to several colums, one for each distinct data type?

Tags: excel

I have got the following data in Excel:

```
Time   Sensor    Mesure
0.10   SensorA   0.233
0.10   SensorF   1
0.11   SensorB   2654 
0.21   SensorB   2755
0.25   SensorA   0.33
0.25   SensorB   2811
0.25   SensorF   -1
```

How can I transform this table into the following one, without using a pivot table?

```
Time   SensorA   SensorB   SensorF 
0.10   0.233                 1
0.11             2654 
0.21             2755
0.25   0.33      2811       -1
```

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use a Pivot Table?  You could use Power Query (available in Excel 2010+)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes the combination of time and sensor is unique:

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMIFS($C:$C,$B:$B,G$1,$A:$A,$F2)),"")
```

[image]